# SQLite: Select colum based on case statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

As an SQL newbie I have a question about selecting  a column based on case values. The SQL below seems like it should work ok (at least to my extremely limited knowledge), but isn't. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT
tbl1.*,
CASE
 WHEN tb11.col1 = "1" THEN tbl2.col1
 WHEN tbl1.col1 = "2" THEN tbl2.col2
end as tbl2_col_select
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2
 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id AND
   tbl1.year = tbl2.year
```

Thanks!

Comment: What _isn't_ working about it?

Comment: just make sure in each case the data type returned should be the same else it will throw an error.

Comment: It unfortunately is returning NA values for the case select, but seems to be joining OK for other items in a larger query.

Comment: M.Ali I think that's the issue. tbl1.col1 is a string and tbl2.col1 / tbl2.col2 are real/float. Any way to get around that?

edit: never mind i misread your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments as I suspected you are returning different data types in different cases therefore you will need to cast it to a data type so in each case returned data type is the same,

One way you can handle this is to cast the data type to match the data types in each case, something like

```
SELECT  tbl1.*
      , CASE
          WHEN tb11.col1 = '1' 
                  THEN tbl2.col1
          WHEN tbl1.col1 = '2' 
                  THEN CAST(tbl2.col2 AS VARCHAR(100))  --<-- Data type of tbl2.col1
        END AS tbl2_col_select
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id AND tbl1.year = tbl2.year
```